# Dimensions of the conjugacy classes of $S_3$ in $\Bbb{C}S_3$.

Tags: representation-theory

Since the conjugacy classes of $S_3$ are $\{1\}$, $\{(1 2), (1 3), (2 3)\}$, and $\{(1 2 3), (1 3 2)\}$, I would think that they have dimensions 1, 3, and 2; respctively (because they are the basis elements of $\Bbb{C}G$). But my textbook says the dimensions are $1, 1$, and $4$...so I'm wondering if I'm missing something.

[image]

"Advanced Modern Algebra" (Joseph Rotman)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, " dimension of conjugacy classes of $S_3$ in $\mathbb CS_3$" doesn't make sense because the conjugacy classes are not vector spaces. If you interpret it to mean "dimensions of the subspaces generated by the conjugacy classes," then your answer is correct; those dimensions are $1,3,2$.  The numbers you quoted as the book's answer, $1,1,4$ are the dimensions of the three simple subalgebras whose direct sum is $\mathbb CS_3$, but that's an entirely different matter.  The only connection between the two (as far as I can see) is that, in any finite group, the number of conjugacy classes equals the number of simple summands in the decomposition of the group algebra.

Comment: Thanks but I need to find the dimensions 1, 1, and 4 without knowing the decomposition of $\Bbb{C}S_3$. I don't know how they did that in the textbook. I will edit my question to include a photo of the page so you can see.

Comment: How to find 1,1,4 depends on what information is available. If you know that the dimensions of the simple components are perfect squares (because they're full matrix algebras) and that the number of simple components equals the number of conjugacy classes, then the problem comes down to writing 6 as the sum of three squares, which can be done only one way: 1+1+4. Alternatively, if you don't know that the dimensions are squares but you've noticed the trivial and sign representations, then  you've got 1 and 1, so the third dimension has to be 4.